# The difference between implication vs consequence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Here in this example a) I want to know the difference between implication($\Rightarrow$) and consequence ($\vdash$)

[image]

Does this exersice want me to show that part 2 is the consequence of part 1?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use MathJax to tender correctly the math expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implication is just a binary logical operation. Consequence means deduction of a formula from a set of formulae using axioms, theorems already proved, and logical rules like modus ponens. Moreover, logical operations have a higher binding (priority) than deduction; this makes parenthesis superfluous and the whole deduction better readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful. But for more clarity I want to understand why in the 3rd point of the proof, B is selected as a hypothesis cause there are only 2 implications before the consequence( and the consequence has a higher priority)? @Wuestenfux